# Tkinter module crashing computer

Tags: python, gui, kernel-module

I have a python program which has been running well for the past several weeks with spyder, but today after making no changes to the code, running the program immediately causes the computer to restart. I think this is an issue with the tkinter module because I'm able to run 'import tkinter' in the terminal with no issues, but running 'python -m tkinter' also causes my computer to restart. Any suggestions for what could be causing this problem?
Python version: 3.7.3
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

The restart is very worrisome, this should not happen in any hypothesis, other than a command to restart. Why don't you reinstall python and tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing Spyder and tkinter is not a good thing as they both run on tkinter.

This restart has happened to a number of people.

Generally speaking, I find the way out of these kinds of situations is to NOT run the latest and greatest code.  If you're running Python 3.7, try 3.6 or not the latest 3.7.